# How to prove that 1 is not an eigenvalue of $T'(x)$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Given a compact continuous operator $T$ from a Banach space $V_1$ to itself and $T$ maps a convex closed bounded set $\mathcal{B}$ into itself, how can we show that 1 is not an eigenvalue of $T'(x)$ (we do not have a closed form expression of $T'$)? Also how can we show that $x \neq T(x)$ for every $x$?

This problem arises from a study of uniqueness of solutions to a boundary value problem.

More details:
 Let $V$ be the following Hilbert space: 
$$V=\lbrace v \in L^2(\Omega)^3, {\rm div} v \in L^2(\Omega), curl v \in  L^2(\Omega)^3\ \qquad {\rm and } \qquad v\cdot n=0 on \partial \Omega \rbrace$$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\Omega$ connected.
 We are given the following BVP:
 \begin{equation*}
 \begin{align} curl b =\lambda(x) (b+B_0) + \nabla p & \\\
  div b=0 &  \\\
 b\cdot n =0  & \qquad {\rm on} \qquad \partial \Omega 
 \end{align} 
  \end{equation*}
 where $n$ is the outgoing normal to $\partial \Omega$ and $B_0 \in L^2(\Omega)^3$ be a potential field.
 $\lambda$ is a function on $\Omega$.
 Then the operator $T$ assigns to every $j \in V_1$ ($V_1=\lbrace v \in V \mid div v =0\rbrace$) the unique solution of the above BVP where $\lambda$ is a solution of the problem:
 $$-\epsilon \Delta \lambda + (j+B_0) \cdot \nabla \lambda =0 \qquad {\rm in }\qquad \Omega$$
 $$ \lambda = \sigma  \qquad {\rm on} \qquad \partial \Omega.$$
 PS: Maybe $T$ is not even linear? Note that I assumed in the begining that $T$ is linear, then I figured that this needs not to be the case, my appologies.

Comment: If $F$ is linear, then $F'(x) = F$. Isn't that a closed form expression?

Comment: I think you should prove that your operator does admit a fixed point, that is $F'(x)\ne x$. You should check the hypothesis of the Banach-Caccioppoli theorem.

Comment: How is that $F'(x)=F$?


Comment: The derivative of a linear map is a linear map, is it not?

Comment: Yes the derivative of a linear map is a linear map. But how does this help in showing that 1 is not an eigenvalue of $F'(x)$?


Comment: Well, if you know that $F$ is linear, then instead of asking about eigenvalues of $F'(x)$, why not ask about eigenvalues of $F$? And at that point, since you have told us nothing about what $V$ and $F$ are, I don't see how one can give a sensible answer to your question in its current form

Comment: The details are lengthy, can I refer to a paper instead?


Comment: For anyone reading this comment thread: the original question had an assumption that the operator in question was linear, hence the comments above. Obviously if it is not necessarily linear then the comments of Dirk and myself do not apply.